# django url tag generating NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, django-templates

When using the django url tag with a dynamic parameter in a Django template, the following snippet:

```html
<ul>
{% for m in markets %}
 <li><a href="{% url 'core:market_detail' market_mic=m.mic %}">{{ m.mic }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

is always generating a NoReverseMatch exception:

```
Error during template rendering
In template D:\X\django\project0\core\templates\markets\index.html, error at line 29

Reverse for 'market_detail' with keyword arguments '{'market_mic': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['core/market/(?P<market_mic>[^/]+)/$']
```

It is configured like this in *core/urls.py*:

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'core'
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /core/market/
    path('market/', views.market_index, name='market_index'),
    # ex: /core/market/XPAR/
    path('market/<str:market_mic>/', views.market_detail, name='market_detail'),
    # ex: /core/market/XPAR/all
    path('market/<str:market_mic>/all', views.market_all_udls, name='market_all_udls'),
```

When trying to get the reverse with the shell (python manage.py shell), it works:

```
In [5]: reverse('core:market_detail', kwargs={'market_mic': 'XPAR'})
Out[5]: '/core/market/XPAR/'
```

It is likely Django is unable to resolve the *market* variable in the url tag while elsewhere it is rendering it as expected.

Comment: Try `reverse('core:market_detail', kwargs={'market_mic': ''})` which is what the error message complains about.

Comment: I get the point that market_mic parameter has an empty value. I just don't understand why since the variable 'm' does exist and so does m.mic. It is likely that inside the url tag, the statement "market_mic=m.mic" is not resolved.

Comment: more likely that `m.mic` is an empty string, no?

Comment: you are right: one of the market has an empty primary key :/ ==> so confused. I could not image that since it was the primary key :( Thanks a lot